# I can not get data in my excel export file in MVC application?

Tags: model-view-controller, xsd, rdlc

Everything is setup well (call method, .xsd file, rdlc file, when i do debugging I can see data in my model, I can download the excel file, but it is still remining empty?! Wher did I'm wrong in my code? Any clue?

My ActionResult in Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Export_StudentStatus()
{
    List<pr_ReportDataGenerate_AllGeneralOverview_Result> model = Context.pr_ReportDataGenerate_AllGeneralOverview().Where(p => p.rdTypeID == 2).ToList();

    ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
    try
    {

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamIds;
        string mimeType = string.Empty, encoding = string.Empty, extension = string.Empty;

        viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
        //viewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
        viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/RDLC/GeneralOverviewStudentStatus.rdlc");
        viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsGeneralOverviewAnnualAwards", model));//ova e DS vo reportot

        viewer.LocalReport.EnableHyperlinks = true;
        byte[] bytes = viewer.LocalReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=GeneralOverviewStudentStatus.xls");
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.End();
        return null;

    }
    finally
    {
        if (viewer != null)
        {
            viewer.Dispose();
            viewer = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Never use images for  code.  Add code as text, formatted as code.  Also, see [mcve].

Comment: OK, Sorry about that (I was thinking to show how i get data from database when I'm in debugging mode, because that I show the picture instead code).

Comment: That's better.  Someone may be able to help based on just that code, but ideally you should provide enough information to reproduce your problem.  Again, see [mcve].  Thanks.